# mat-nav-item is not a known element

Tags: angular

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {  MatButtonModule,MatMenuModule , MatTabsModule ,  MatToolbarModule,MatIconModule,  MatCardModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

I have imported all required material module but still I am getting error mentioned in subject. I don't understand which module I have missed to import. Version I used for my project is as below.

Angular CLI 6.1.5
Angular     6.1.9
Node        8.11.1
@angular/material "^6.4.7",
@angular/cdk      "^6.4.7",

My HTML code

```
<mat-nav-bar>
  <mat-nav-item mat-nav-href="#/" name="page3">Home</mat-nav-item>
  <mat-nav-item mat-nav-href="#/about" name="page3">About</mat-nav-item>
</mat-nav-bar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular Material there are no `mat-nav-bar` and `mat-nav-item`. Use `mat-nav-list` and `mat-list-item` instead (add `MatListModule` to your `MaterialModule`):

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <mat-list-item routerLink="/">Home</mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

However, your `MaterialModule` looks fine. In case you haven't done it yet, you need to include this module within your `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Yes MaterialModule is already included into AppModule, I have now used your html code & added MatListModule but now getting error "mat-list-item is not a known element"

Comment: Mmh. Do other components from Angular Material, e.g. `<mat-toolbar></mat-toolbar>`, work?

Comment: Added mat-toolbar-row in materialModule but now mat-toolbar-row not known element issue. My app.modules.ts code is      

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: No need to include `mat-toolbar-row` since it is not a module but part of `MatToolbarModule`. `imports: [BrowserModule]` should be `imports: [BrowserModule, MaterialModule]`. Follow [these steps](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started), or just do `ng add @angular/material`.

Comment: Yes adding MaterialModule in app.module solved the issue. I have accepted the answer.